# Can I use Kendall's correlation to determine the correlation between continuous and binary variables?

Tags: correlation, binary-data, continuous-data, computational-statistics

I have a dataset where the first 6 columns correspond to binary entries referring to sick/not sick and 2 additional columns with age and a specific score (dim of the dataset 60x8). I need to generate a correlation matrix from the data. My dataset is pretty small (60 observations) and it doesnt follow a normal distribution. Can I use Kendall's correlation to compute the coefficients for binary and continuous variables? Google keeps telling me that I should use point-biserial correlation for this, but it seems to follow Pearson's correlation which is suited for normally distributed data - sadly not my case.

Im thankful for any critic and tips.

I tried Kendall's vs Spearman's correlation and concluded that Kendall's is better suited due to the small dataset size.

Comment: It depends on what you're after. Different correlation measures quite literally measure different things about the relationship, so it doesn't make sense to refer to "the" correlation when considering multiple distinctly different measures. If you are specifically interested in what Kendall correlation measures, then sure, you could use it (at least a version that appropriately deals with the heavy ties; off the top of my head I think $\tau_b$ would at least be able to attain the $-1$ and $+1$ limits).

Comment: Thanks a lot. My goal is to visually represent the association between the variables, i.e. their correlation (e.g. is there any association between the incidence of diseases with the score of the medical test). 
I have 6 different diseases, 1 age, and 1 score column of a medical test for the columns of my dataset. Would Spearman or Kendall be a good fit for that? 
Should I transform my non normally distributed data and when it's normalized, apply Pearson's correlation?

Comment: 1. "***Visually represent*** association between variables" sounds like you would look for a *display* (or a set of displays for multiple variables), rather than a number. 2. Transforming data will alter the linear dependence that a Pearson correlation measures (if it was linear, you will make the relationship *nonlinear*, rendering Pearson unsuitable; alternatively, if it was already nonlinear, why use Pearson for that?). You don't need normal marginal distributions for a Pearson correlation to make sense as a measure of association.